# bash - command substitution is omitting whitespaces

Tags: string, bash, command-substitution

I have a command that is returning a string with a leading whitespace that gets eaten when I use command substitution

```
> echo "  test"
  test

> echo $(echo "  test")
test
```

Why is this happening and what can I do about it?

Comment: Use: `echo "$(echo "  test")"` to see whitespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can double-quote command substitution to preserve that,

```
echo "$(echo "  test")"
  test
```

From the `man bash` on  page,

> Command Substitution
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines
>   deleted.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but they may be removed during word splitting.
>
> If the *substitution appears within **double quotes***, word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the results.

Comment: unfortunately, seems it always do rtrim:  
`echo "$(echo -e "\n\ntest\n\n\n")"`